# how to call add to cart interaction data with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I use this tool [add to cart interaction](https://codyhouse.co/gem/add-to-cart-interaction/) to make an interaction exactly like I use in the demo below, but my question is: when I push "checkout button" **how can I send the data to php?** or **how can I call this information with php to the checkout page**?

here is a demo of how it works:

```css
a {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://yuridesign.com.mx/otro/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://yuridesign.com.mx/otro/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://yuridesign.com.mx/js/cartmain.js"></script>

<a class="cd-add-to-cart" data-price="25.99" data-name="Anillo">Add to cart</a>
 <div class="cd-cart-container empty">
  <a href="#0" class="cd-cart-trigger">
   Cart
   <ul class="count"> <!-- cart items count -->
    <li>0</li>
    <li>0</li>
   </ul> <!-- .count -->
  </a>
 
  <div class="cd-cart">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
     <h2>Cart</h2>
     <span class="undo">Product removed. <a href="#0">undo</a></span>
    </header>
    
    <div class="body">
     <ul>
      <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
     </ul>
    </div>
 
    <footer>
     <a href="#0" class="checkout btn"><em>Checkout - $<span>0</span></em></a>
    </footer>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .cd-cart -->
 </div> <!-- cd-cart-container -->
```

Comment: The documentation for that component seems a bit... light.  But on that page they show this line for adding a product to "the cart": `cartList.prepend(productAdded);`  So it seems that there's a variable called `cartList` somewhere which holds the data you're looking for?  Though the data appears to just be an HTML string.  If that's the case then, honestly, I wouldn't recommend using this tool.  If all of the data is stored in HTML strings then you need to *parse* it *from* that HTML.  Which is less than ideal.

Comment: and cannot be added with ajax and php?

Comment: Nobody said that.  You can make an AJAX request to your PHP code any time you like.  In the question you're asking how to get the data that you need to send to PHP.  From the documentation of the tool you're using (of which there is *very little*), it looks like the "data" is raw HTML.  So, unless that tool offers any other option, you'd need to parse the data you're looking for from the HTML.  Or manually store it separately when you add it to the HTML.  As it stands this question seems very broad, basically asking how to use JavaScript/AJAX/PHP in general.